# Can't create ssis package in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I can't seem to figure out why I can't create new SSIS packages in VS2015. I have installed:

- VS2015 community ed.
- SQL Server 2016
- SSDT
- SSMS

If I right click in the solution explorer on "SSIS packages" there is no dropdown menu, which should be there.

If I right click in the Connection manager area, nothing happens, no drop down, nothing.

Am kind of clueless, can't find anything on Google regarding this issue.

Comment: Also - SSIS isn't showing in the menu bar on top. I Can however create a new integration services project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the basic steps to create a new SSIS package.

1. Create or open an Integration Services project
2. Right click the "SSIS Packages" folder
3. Choose "New SSIS Package"
4. Follow the prompts

[image]

If this is not possible to follow these steps on your machine then there is a problem with your installation. Make sure your version of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) matches your Visual Studio version. SSDT can be downloaded from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx. I hope this helps.

Comment: exactly step 2 is not possible to do. If I right click it, no menu shows up. I have tried updating and repairing SSDT, also from within VS, but it just doesn't work..

Comment: Which SSDT version did you install?

Comment: allright - after finishing the 4th update of the SSDT package (everytime the same update file, version 14.0.60812.0) and the 4th reboot, it now works.  No clue what the actual problem was, but updating 4 times fixed it.