# What other dependencies do I need to install in Visual Studio 2019 Express / Community to open a dtsx SISS file in the GUI?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019, ssis-2019

When I installed VS2019 Express I made sure to include the `Data storage and processing` Workload, I also created an `SQL Server Database Project`, but when I add the `.dtsx` (SSIS) file to my project it still doesn't open in the GUI.  I know there is GUI information included in the file because I can see the XML character entities where separate diagram XML is written with them.

There also appears to be something that looks like a .NET assembly in there with some C# code and some kind of Base64 encoding, who knows if it's zipped or what kind of file or string it contains.

I've looked at the XML within the file, and I'm *fairly certain* I understand what it does, but it's a rather convoluted xml file so I'd like to use VS2019 Express to find out for sure what it does using the GUI.

Are there any other dependencies I need to install?

This [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983857/cant-create-ssis-package-in-visual-studio) has some answers in it, but I don't see of the things they mention listed in the `Individual Components` on the installation screen.

Comment: Ah, so it's the basic Microsoft people know how to use this, so lets make it do the same thing, but rename it to six or seven different things that do the same thing.

Comment: i suggested editing the question title to be more abstract since this question is widely asked (changes are made in latest version) and an abstract title will prevent others to ask the same question multiple time. similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080651/visual-studio-2019-ssdt At the end, you're the original poster and you have the right to reject my edit. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should download and install the Integration Services Projects extension:

- [SQL Server Integration Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects)

Refering to the [following documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#changes-in-ssdt-for-visual-studio-2019):

> For Analysis Services, Integration Services or Reporting Services projects, install the appropriate extension(s) from the marketplace (What you need to install)

Comment: You will also need to install the SQL Connection manager that is referenced in Known issue #1 from the SSIS Marketplace link that Hadi provided.