# How to build a SSIS project (*.dtproj) using Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 on build server

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, build-tools

We are trying to build an SSIS project `*.dtproj` on our build server using Visual Studio Build Tools 2019.

Would be great if someone could give an advice on how to get it work.

On a dev machine when using `devenv.exe` from Visual Studio 2019 it will build the project but on the build server we have only the build tools.

`Data storage and processing` workload is installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138300/what-other-dependencies-do-i-need-to-install-in-visual-studio-2019-express-com/56138425#56138425

Comment: @Hadi

"... from Visual Studio 2019 it will build the project but on the build server we have **only the build tools** ..."

Comment: You need to have VS installed on build Server. Create dedicated Build Server if needed or conflicting with something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Visual Studio installed on the build server.

Run the following code from PowerShell or adjust for for CMD:

```
&'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com'`
'D:\Source\solution.sln'`
/rebuild 'Debug' /Project  'D:\Source\project.dtproj'`
/ProjectConfig 'Development' /Out 'C:\Temp\build.log'
```

Link for discussion about licensing for VS on build server:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01ccff7b-07c1-4a0a-8312-c1f77703b5b5/visual-studio-licensing-on-build-server?forum=visualstudiogeneral