# How do I build a specific dtproj file within a solution?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, devenv

I have a solution full of SSIS projects, and I'm trying to build a single one via command line.  I know I need to use the `devenv.com` executable, and if I use `devenv.com solution.sln /Rebuild` it will process the whole set of projects.  However, I cannot seem to get the additional parameters correct.  When I try `devenv.com solution.sln /Rebuild "Development" /Project "projname"`, I get an enigmatic `The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.`  Which parameter?  What should it be? I've tried replicating [this answer's syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56191841/167889), but I get the same error.  How do I find out *what* parameter is incorrect?  So far the closest I can get is to rename the `.sln` file so it can't be found and just specify the `.dtproj` file.

Comment: Is  `/Project "projname"` over simplified or should it be `/Project "projname.dtproj"`

Comment: omg, I don't know why that wasn't more clear.  I guess that's all I was missing!